# Oracle DB: encoding for RU

Tags: oracle

Good day. I try to retrieve russian characters with Oracle db. I try to set env. variables, change NLS_LANG in preferences of the SQL Developer... And what i have now:

```
PARAMETER                      VALUE                                                          
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   RUSSIAN                                                          
NLS_TERRITORY                  RUSSIA                                                           
NLS_CURRENCY                   ¿.                                                               
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               RUSSIA                                                           
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,                                                               
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN                                                        
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD.MM.RR                                                         
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              RUSSIAN                                                          
NLS_SORT                       RUSSIAN                                                          
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH24:MI:SSXFF                                                    
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF                                           
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR                                                
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR                                       
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              ¿.                                                               
NLS_COMP                       BINARY                                                           
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE                                                             
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE                                                            

 17 rows selected 

COL1       COL2                                     
---------- --------------------------------------------------
¿¿¿¿       ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿ ¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿
```

Comment: So, why russian symbols are not shown?

Comment: What is your database character set? What is `NLS_LANG` set to? Probably you are using a client character set that cannot encode cyrillic letters.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `RUSSIAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251` it's value of the NLS_LANG. But `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `WE8MSWIN1252`. It's a problem? How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database character set cannot encode cyrillic characters, so you won't be able to store them in the database.

You have two options:

1. Create a new database with character set `AL32UTF8`. This is the better option.
2. Create the fields that are to contain cyrillic characters as `NVARCHAR`.